# Should I apply for a full-time position if I am only able to work for a few months?

Tags: internship, work-experience, student, tech-industry, fulltime

I'm currently pursuing by Bachelors degree and I will finish this one in September. Next year September (2018) I would like to start a Masters degree. Since I have one year now without having a study, I would love to work for a company in the US and gain working experience. But, since it is only one year (probably only 6-8 months if the whole onboarding process is finished),  my question is:

*Is it recommended to apply for a full-time position at a tech company when there are only a few months left?*

(I am thinking about applying for a tech company. Their internships are only available for students currently enrolled in a program. So I guess a full time position is the only option.)

Answer (score 2):

If you apply to various contract firms who supply W-2 employees for contract work, there is a very strong possibility you could both be honest about availability and find an excellent fit with a company that only needs your services for a short time.

I would hesitate to "fail to inform" a potential employer of limited availability... it would make it difficult to explain the brief employment period in future interviews (after you've finished the masters).

If you make your availability known to employers, you may not find a "good fit", but it's also possible that the employer would be interested in "test driving" and possibly another job after you've finished you masters. -- The corporation I work for has the ability to have employees who are similar to interns, but don't have the official title intern.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't *advertise* that you intend on only being there for X months but I would say yes apply for roles - if nothing else you don't know what the future will bring and you're best off taking care of yourself and your needs. Assuming you intend on working/studying in the tech industry then the experience will do you far more good than an unrelated temp job somewhere. Plus you get to earn some money as well so it's win-win.